# How do I change base URL when moving site from sub-directory to domain root?

Tags: uri

I have developed a site in a sub-directory and now will be pointing a live URL to it. What do I need to do to ensure that the relative links in the menus etc will work under this new configuration. I have read that settings need to be changed in sites/default/settings.php however looking at the file it does not appear that a "base" URL is specified ... same with the .htaccess file under the root.
This may be a fundamental question, but in WordPress for example having a new "base" URL requires a settings change otherwise relative links will end up pointing to a 404 page ... how is this handled in Drupal (7)

Comment: did you uncomment 'RewriteBase /drupal' from .htaccess file and set your folder's name instead of 'drupal'?

Comment: Could you complete the question title please? You seem to have stopped mid

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have made customizations to the URL-related settings in .htaccess or your settings.php, you won't need to update anything. Simply move your site, then clear the cache either via the "Clear Cache" button (on the Performance admin page), or the [Drush](https://drupal.org/project/drush) utility, and you should be good to go.

Comment: First, it's way safer to disable cache before move and re-enable it after, sometimes with messed cache it's impossible to execute cache clear as one can't even load GUI. And what about links in content? From my experience on big site there will be dozen with full URL instead of relative one.